# SQL table for Address and Localization

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I need to save a list of Places and Persons in a Database including their Addresses and Latitude / Longitude. Sometimes I have an address other times only Latitude / Longitude other times none. So I have:

```
create table dbo.Persons (
  Id int identity not null primary key clustered (Id),      
  AddressId int not null,   
  Name nvarchar (100) null,
  Localization geography null
)

create table dbo.Places (
  Id int identity not null primary key clustered (Id),      
  AddressId int not null,   
  Name nvarchar (100) null,
  Localization geography null
)

create table dbo.Addresses (
  Id int identity not null primary key clustered (Id),      
  CityId int not null,
  Street nvarchar (100) null,
  PostalCode nvarchar (100) null,
)

create table dbo.Cities (
  Id int identity not null primary key clustered (Id),      
  Name nvarchar (100) null
)
```

I have two questions:

1. Should I move the Localization from Places and Persons to Address?
   I am doing this way because I can have an address and not a Localization or vice versa.
2. Is there a way to improve my database scheme?

Comment: Probably better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would remove Localization from Persons.  It exists in Places.

You say a Person may have an address, a localization, both, or none?  If that is true, then make Persons.AddressID nullable (if it is valid to not have an address).  Also, add a PlacesID (nullable) to Persons.

Answer (score 0):

You database model looks fine to me. Only that `AddressId` must be nullable in `Persons` and `Places`, as its optional. As you say you will always only have either have an address or latitude / longitude, it seems perfect. But you should add a check constraint on both `Persons` and `Places` to ensure not to have both fields filled at the same time.

If, however, you think you might want some time to be able to store both address and latitude / longitude for a person or place, you would want to move `Localization` to address, because it then is an integral part thereof. If you kept your datamodel as is, you could get inconsistencies by changing an address and not changing the corresponding localization (or vice versa). When moving the localization to address, its `cityid` would have to be made nullable then of course, because you may have "addresses" that only consist of latitude / logitude with the city unknown.

As to the overall design: Will persons and places differ much from each other? So far they contain the same columns. Hence you may want to use one table PersonOrPlace only instead and add a type column saying whether an entry is a person or a place (or have a flag IsPerson instead).

Comment: Yes, Places and Persons will differ a lot ... I just posted an example.